# How should I store and revoke OAuth2 authorizations and/or refresh tokens?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm implementing the OAuth2 authorization code flow in a proof-of-concept application - so pure ASP.NET MVC, not using DotNetOpenAuth or any other auth frameworks - and I'm scratching my head about how to handle revocation.

My implementation works like so:

1. User logs on to FooApp (the OAuth2 client application - a website)
2. FooApp redirects the user to www.myserver.com/accounts/authorize
3. User says "yep, FooApp can access my stuff"
4. I generate an **authorization code**, and **store this code at myserver.com** along with the client ID, user ID and scopes the user has authorized. (In my implementation, the authorization code is the GUID key of the database record storing who authorised what.)
5. The user is redirected back to FooApp
6. FooApp makes an HTTP request to MyServer, including the authorization code
7. MyServer looks up that authorization code, verifies that it is valid and has not expired. It marks the authorization code as used - since OAuth2 authorization codes MUST be single-use and short-lived - and then responds to FooApp with a **refresh token** and **access token**
8. FooApp uses the access_token to access the user's data. When the access_token expires after 10 minutes, FooApp uses the refresh_token to get another one.
9. After a couple of weeks, the user decides they're fed up with FooApp accessing their data, so they log in to MyServer and revoke FooApp's authorization.

OK, here's where the spec gets a bit fuzzy on recommended implementation, and I think it boils down to what happens when the user revokes the authorization.

**Option 1:**

> The refresh token is a self-contained encrypted string containing the user ID, client ID and scope. It is not stored anywhere. When the access token expires, the client sends me a refresh token. I decrypt
>   this, and check whether I still have a valid Authorization record on file for
>   that user/client/scope combination. If I do, I send them a new access
>   token. If not, I return an `invalid_grant` error.
>
> In this scenario, revoking the authorization would mean marking the
>   Authorization record in my database as revoked (or just deleting it
>   entirely). No authorization record -> refresh tokens won't work -> FooApp can't access data any more.

**Option 2:**

> I store the refresh token in my database, along with the client_id,
>   user id and the scopes authorized in that token. When I get a request
>   to refresh the token, I find the refresh_token record, check it hasn't
>   been revoked, etc.
>
> In this scenario, "revoking the authorization" would be implemented by marking > the refresh token in my DB as revoked, or by deleting it.
>
> Additionally - in this scenario, I can't see any reason to keep the authorization on file once it's been exchanged for tokens. If the user wishes to know which applications have access to their MyServer data, I just query the DB for all their un-revoked refresh tokens and associated scopes.

As far as I can tell, either option will satisfy the requirements of the OAuth2 specification whilst allowing users to view, and revoke, all the authorizations that are currently active on their MyServer account. One limitation is that option 1 wouldn't allow for multiple separate OAuth2 token sets to be issued to the same client application for the same user - but I can't think of any scenario where you'd want to do this.

What would you recommend? Encrypt tokens and store authorizations? Delete the authorizations after use, and store the refresh tokens? Or does it really not matter?

Comment: We are at a same stage of implementing revocation support too. Since authorization codes have to be persisted in the database, Option 1 looks better since it does not require the refresh token to be persisted. Another option (Option 3) would be to check for existence of the access token record in database. If it exists and it is expired, the refresh token end point call would go ahead and generate a new access token, deleting the older one.

Comment: @AndyDufresne in my implementation, access tokens are never persisted - they're encrypted. The only place they're "stored" is in the client application. This means my resource server doesn't need to do a database lookup/API call - it can work out the user ID, expiry and scopes by decrypting the token, which decouples the authorization server from the resource server.